# fxHide.gt-sm Not working

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I have the following div and it shows a login button on a nav bar, but if the screen is small I want to hide this button. For some reason when I add the `fxHide.gt-sm=true` it doesn't hide when I make the screen smaller. How can I fix this?

```
 <div fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <ng-template #login>
          <button 
          mat-icon-button
          [routerLink]="['/auth']" 
          [style.width]="'auto'"
          [style.overflow]="'visible'"
          matTooltip="Login or Register"
          class="topbar-button-right">
            <span>Login</span>
            <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
 </div>
```

Comment: any updates?...

Answer (score 7):

What you want:

- Default behavior: shown
- If lt-md (less than medium screen) => hide

With your current implementation you have:

- Default behavior: shown
- If gt-sm (greater than small screen) => hide

Now, what you want translates into:

```
<div fxShow fxHide.lt-md>
```

You could invert the logic into

```
<div fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi, I tried using fxHide fxShow.gt-sm but still it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

`fxHide.gt-sm` means hide it when it's greater than small. Change it to `fxShow.gt-sm` if you only want it visible on larger screen.

Comment: No luck. I've also tried `fxHide.lt-sm="true"`. I've used `fxHide.lt-sm` in my project before and its working so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same thing but after importing `FlexLayoutModule` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the OP is having issues making the fxHide command work at all, this question may be a duplicate of [Angular Material FlexLayout fxHide does not hide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54405731/4440629)

You must ensure that FlexLayout is imported in all modules that wish to use it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62672981/4440629